# Wavefunction overlap in graphene

Tags: correlation-functions, graphene

In calculation of the response functions of graphene we need to calculate the 4-point correlation function of the form :

$$ \langle T \rho(q,\tau)\rho(-q,0)\rangle $$

The article I'm reading states that the result is the same as the one for 2d electron gas except that a factor of 
$$ f^{ss'}(q)=\frac{1}{2}(1+ss' \frac{k^2 +k.q}{k |k+q|})$$
appears which was not in the expression for 2DE and is related to band overlap of wavefunctions.
I'm completely unfamiliar with graphene and I don't know how this factor appears.
Here is the article : [Dynamical polarization of graphene at finite doping](http://arxiv.org/abs/cond-mat/0610630)

Comment: it would help to link also the article.

Comment: They write the density as $\rho = \rho_a + \rho_b$. Thus when calculating the density-density correlation function you get terms like $\rho_a^2$ that give the usual $\frac{\Delta n_F}{\Delta E}$ term, and terms like $\rho_a \rho_b$ that will likely introduce a form factor.